# context failed to start using apache tomcat and netbeans

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, netbeans-7.1

when i tried to run my project using apache tomcat6.0.35 server i get these following errors

```
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2719)
... 54 more
```

here it shows error in the web.xml file both errors `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` and

`/localhost/knowledgecenter/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 23; Error at (11, 23: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name validfiles1` at a time when i run the project

```
Sep 04, 2012 4:40:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/knowledgecenter/WEB-INF/web.xml
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/knowledgecenter/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 23; Error at (11, 23: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name validfiles1
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1741)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2898)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1076)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1500)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:849)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:351)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name validfiles1
at    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2739)
at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:2719)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethodN(IntrospectionUtils.java:959)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.CallMethodMultiRule.end(WebRuleSet.java:789)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Rule.end(Rule.java:229)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1138)
... 47 more
```

the same project runs fine under glassfish,but it fails in tomcat.iam using netbeans 7.1.
i get this warning during the clean and build process

```
init:
undeploy-clean:
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build
Deleting directory /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/dist
check-clean:
clean:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
Created dir: /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/META-INF
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/META-INF
Copying 53 files to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
Copying 1 file to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/lib
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Created dir: /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/empty
Compiling 15 source files to /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/build/web/WEB-INF/classes
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning
compile:
compile-jsps:
Created dir: /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/dist
Building jar: /home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/knowledgecenter/dist/knowledgecenter.war
do-dist:
dist:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: do you have any file with the name `validfiles1` in your work space?

Comment: ya...the file is present

Comment: Could you post the content of your web.xml ?

Comment: i have solved the issue,it was with the web.xml.first it was executing the servlet mapping and then the class.need to be reversed in order to get work.any how after solving the issue iam facing a new problem.chk this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274481/form-action-is-not-calling-the-servlet